# Trying to update total column by # answers of selected 'Yes'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

everyone.

My goal is to add the total number of 'Yes' answers, and I am having a bit of trouble. I would also like the total column to subtract, but I haven't gotten there yet as the # of 'Yes's isn't showing correctly. FYI, I am calling the function calculateSum()

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Here's the code.

```
HTML:
-- Question
<li id="qid61915_1" value="11" style="margin: 20px 0px 30px 0px" ;="" required="true">Test Question

-- Yes
<div class="radio answerRadio width-70"><label><input type="radio" name="qid61915Radio_1" 
id="aid73380_1" class="currentStepAnswer" value="Yes">Yes</label></div>

-- No
<div class="radio answerRadio width-70"><label><input type="radio" name="qid61915Radio_1" 
id="aid73381_1" class="currentStepAnswer" value="No">No</label></div></li>
```

Javascript:

```
function calculateSum() {
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName('currentStepAnswer');
    var i; 
    var s = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
       if (e[i].value == "Yes") { 
           s++ ; 
       }
 }
       $("#fallRiskTotal").html(s.toFixed(1));

}
```

-- This JavaScript is being called in another function that displays the Q's and A's

```
   if (currentQuestionNum == 11) {
      riskAssessTitles += "<hr>";
      riskAssessTitles += "<h4 class='left' style='margin: 20px 0px 15px 0px';>Total:
      <span id='fallRiskTotal' style='padding:20px 0px 0px 3px';></span></h4>";
      $(riskAssessTitles).insertAfter($('#qid' + qid + '_' + instanceNum));
  }

  calculateSum();
```

Comment: why not `$(".currentStepAnswer[value='yes']:checked").length` ?

Comment: @Twisty yeah, it could work, but I am trying to make the total column dynamic. + or - based on user input.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function calculateSum() {
    return $(".currentStepAnswer[value='Yes']:checked").length;
  }

  function calculatePerc() {
    var y = $(".currentStepAnswer[value='Yes']:checked").length;
    var t = $("ul li").length;
    return y / t;
  }

  $(".currentStepAnswer").change(function() {
    $("#fallRiskTotal").html(calculateSum().toFixed(2) + " " + (calculatePerc() * 100).toFixed(2) + "%");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="qid61915_1" value="11" style="margin: 20px 0px 30px 0px" required="true">Test Question
    <div class="radio answerRadio width-70"><label><input type="radio" name="qid61915Radio_1" 
id="aid73380_1" class="currentStepAnswer" value="Yes">Yes</label></div>
    <div class="radio answerRadio width-70"><label><input type="radio" name="qid61915Radio_1" 
id="aid73381_1" class="currentStepAnswer" value="No">No</label></div>
  </li>
  <li id="qid61915_2" value="12" style="margin: 20px 0px 30px 0px" required="true">Test Question
    <div class="radio answerRadio width-70"><label><input type="radio" name="qid61915Radio_2" 
id="aid73380_2" class="currentStepAnswer" value="Yes">Yes</label></div>
    <div class="radio answerRadio width-70"><label><input type="radio" name="qid61915Radio_2" 
id="aid73381_2" class="currentStepAnswer" value="No">No</label></div>
  </li>
  <li id="qid61915_3" value="13" style="margin: 20px 0px 30px 0px" required="true">Test Question
    <div class="radio answerRadio width-70"><label><input type="radio" name="qid61915Radio_3" 
id="aid73380_3" class="currentStepAnswer" value="Yes">Yes</label></div>
    <div class="radio answerRadio width-70"><label><input type="radio" name="qid61915Radio_3" 
id="aid73381_1" class="currentStepAnswer" value="No">No</label></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="fallRiskTotal"></div>
```

Comment: it seems as though you literally gave me the answer, but it still is not working on my part. I am not getting any results to output to the console.

Comment: now I have output, but it's 0. I am going to keep working through it. I really appreciate your help !

Comment: @AlexGreenwood my answer does not output to console it followed your example and outputs to `fallRiskTotal`. If this is not the case, please update your OP.

Comment: You're right, it does not. I only wanted to see what I am doing wrong, and ensuring I am getting an output allows me to know I am on the right track.

Comment: If you're wondering what I did to make it work, please see below. From there, it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// function to return # of 'Yes's
function calculateSum() {
    return $(".currentStepAnswer[value='Yes']:checked").length;
};

$(function() {
    $(".currentStepAnswer").change(function() {
        $("#fallRiskTotal").html(calculateSum().toFixed(1));
    });
});
```